# how to parsing value of json file with php class

Tags: php, json, class

i try to parsing json with format like this

```
{
  "bossresponse":{
    "responsecode":"200",
    "web":{
      "start":"0",
      "count":"50",
      "totalresults":"88300000",
      "results":[
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/naruto.viz.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/naruto.viz.com\/",
          "dispurl":"naruto<\/b>.viz.com",
          "title":"NARUTO<\/b> Shippuden - OFFICIAL U.S. Site - Watch the Anime ...",
          "abstract":"Check out the latest discussions! TOPICS. AUTHOR"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/naruto.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/naruto.com\/",
          "dispurl":"naruto<\/b>.com",
          "title":"NARUTO<\/b>",
          "abstract":""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and when i parse with this function

```
$json = file_get_contents("test.json");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                        new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
                        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                //echo "$key:\n";
                if($key == "web"){
                    foreach($val as $key1 => $results){
                        if(is_array($results)){
                            if($key1 == "results"){
                                foreach($results as $key2 => $v){
                                    if (is_array($v)) {
                                        foreach ($v as $v1) {
                                           echo $v[title];

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                //echo $results;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    //echo $val;
                }
            } else {
                //echo "$key => $val\n";
            }
        }
```

it's successfull but i think my code is crazy code,you can look foreach and foreach very much is not good to maintenance. i want to implement in OOP like with class...
can you help me how i can do that?any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason this won't work?

```
$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$results = $json['bossresponse']['web']['results'];
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result['title'];
}
```

Comment: viola that is work ...with this the code is simple but powerfull...thanks very much...